# wp_remote_get sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: errors, ssl, wp-remote-get

I'm attempting to retrieve remote content with [wp_remote_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) but I'm getting the following error returned : 'sslv3 alert handshake failure'.

I've tried using 'sslverify'   => false in the args array, but to no avail. This was working fine on the dev server, but no more, so I'm assuming it's a server/apache configuration issue. Any ideas on how I can address this, either by modifying the calling function or server config?